# Can this be achieved using CSS3?

Tags: html, css

The image I'm about to show you displays the layout I want for the uploaded images on my website.

[image]

Unfortunately I am currently achieving this on the back-end by creating 4 flex-box columns, then looping through all images and splitting them in 4 groups. Then I loop through each group and display that group in 1 column. The result is that:

`image 1` goes in `column 1`,

`image 2` goes in `column 2`,

`image 3` goes in `column 3`,

`image 4` goes in `column 4`,

then

`image 5` goes in `column 1` again and

`image 6` goes in `column 2`

Even I understand that it is very very unwise to do something so demanding on the back-end just to achieve some styling and that's why I've been wondering if I can achieve this using pure CSS3.

I have decided to also upload my back-end code which allowed me to achieve this.

```
<div class="flex-grid-home">
@php($count = 0)
@foreach($images as $image)
    @if ($count % 4 == 0)
        @php($images1[] = $image)
    @elseif($count % 4 == 1)
        @php($images2[] = $image)
    @elseif($count % 4 == 2)
        @php($images3[] = $image)
    @else
        @php($images4[] = $image)
    @endif
    @php($count++)
@endforeach

<div class="col-home-1">
@if (!empty($images1))
    @foreach($images1 as $image)
        <div class='imageContainer'>
            <div class="stickyContainer blackGradient">
                <h1 class='imageTitle'>{{$image->name}}</h1>
                <img class='uploadedImg' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/thumbnails/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image'/>
                <a class='specialA' href='{{url("image/".$image->id)}}'></a>
                @auth
                <div class='votingContainer'>
                    <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 1 ) ? "liked" : "like" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
                    <p class='voteCount'>{{ $image->upvotes - $image->downvotes }}</p>
                    <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 0 ) ? "disliked" : "dislike" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
                </div>
                @endauth
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach

@endif
</div>

<div class="col-home-2">
@if (!empty($images2))
    @foreach($images2 as $image)
        <div class='imageContainer'>
            <div class="stickyContainer blackGradient">
                <h1 class='imageTitle'>{{$image->name}}</h1>
                <img class='uploadedImg' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/thumbnails/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image'/>
                <a class='specialA' href='{{url("image/".$image->id)}}'></a>
                @auth
                <div class='votingContainer'>
                    <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 1 ) ? "liked" : "like" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
                    <p class='voteCount'>{{ $image->upvotes - $image->downvotes }}</p>
                    <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 0 ) ? "disliked" : "dislike" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
                </div>
                @endauth
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
</div>

<div class="col-home-3">
    @if (!empty($images3))
            @foreach($images3 as $image)
                <div class='imageContainer'>
                    <div class="stickyContainer blackGradient">
                        <h1 class='imageTitle'>{{$image->name}}</h1>
                        <img class='uploadedImg' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/thumbnails/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image'/>
                        <a class='specialA' href='{{url("image/".$image->id)}}'></a>
                        @auth
                        <div class='votingContainer'>
                            <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 1 ) ? "liked" : "like" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
                            <p class='voteCount'>{{ $image->upvotes - $image->downvotes }}</p>
                            <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 0 ) ? "disliked" : "dislike" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
                        </div>
                        @endauth
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
    @endif
</div>

<div class="col-home-4">
    @if (!empty($images4))
            @foreach($images4 as $image)
                <div class='imageContainer'>
                    <div class="stickyContainer blackGradient">
                        <h1 class='imageTitle'>{{$image->name}}</h1>
                        <img class='uploadedImg' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/thumbnails/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image'/>
                        <a class='specialA' href='{{url("image/".$image->id)}}'></a>
                        @auth
                        <div class='votingContainer'>
                            <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 1 ) ? "liked" : "like" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
                            <p class='voteCount'>{{ $image->upvotes - $image->downvotes }}</p>
                            <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 0 ) ? "disliked" : "dislike" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
                        </div>
                        @endauth
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
    @endif
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear: the posted image is what you *want*, but the text description is describing your current (unwanted) result? For the ease of our reproducing your problem could you post the [mcve] code you're working with?

Comment: I suppose that the best way is to use javascript for that purpose. So that you achieve needed result and not use server resources

Comment: Are you looking to achieve something like what pinterest does? Displaying a bunch of images on the screen while taking up as much screen space as possible? https://i.imgur.com/aJqVL0D.jpg

Comment: Do the images have to be in a specific order? Or is it just about them flowing around each other and filling up space as efficiently as possible?

Comment: To That Umbrella Guy, Yes I believe this is what I'm trying to achieve. To Keeghan McGarry - When I display all the images using PHP loop, the newest ones are displayed first and my goal is to have the at the top side even after the styling.

Comment: If you want, you can enter my website http://onyx.space/ , log in using username and password Admin and upload a couple of images to see how they stack.

Comment: David Thomas, the image shows both what I want and what I have already achieved. The problem is that I have achieved this using the back-end trick of taking all the images, splitting them in 4 arrays and looping through each one of those 4 arrays. One array in each column, which allows me to achieve this look but is very inefficient for the back-end since if I have a lot of images, it'll get really slow. That's why I want to know whether I can achieve that just by using CSS3 and maybe JavaScript. I've actually uploaded the PHP code which I used to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved.
You'd have to learn CSS-grid to design it that way.
Check this out: [Learn CSS Grid in 5 minutes](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-css-grid-in-5-minutes-f582e87b1228)

also, 
first do it with background colors, to make the task a bit easier, and then you have two options:

1. Put images inside those `div`.
2. Use `background: url('image.png');` property.

If you want to do it in vanilla CSS then,
follow these steps:

1. Create 4 `div` with `class='column'`, now in CSS

`.column {
    width: 25vw;    //here 25 because, since we have 4 columns(100/4=25)
}`

2. Place `div` inside those columns with `100%` width, and whatever height you want.

Comment: What is the difference with flex-box? Using that doesn't really help to sort images into columns

Comment: you can use flex as well, here's a link for that: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-css-flexbox-in-5-minutes-b941f0affc34

Comment: Flex-box is actually better option, since it would also help to make your layout responsive on mobile devices as well.

Comment: As far as I see the user wants to divide images into columns using CSS3. Not asking how to achieve the columns.

Comment: At the end of they day, I don't really even need to have 4 columns, I just need to achieve this layout. I used the 4 columns because that was the only way I could think of. If I could loop through the images and display them in 1 containing div and then style them with CSS3 to achieve this look, it would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it feels like the backend is doing too much work.  Ideally, the backend will return a linear list of resources in some desired order, and the frontend becomes responsible for displaying it to the user.

Unfortunately, trying to achieve your exact layout is nontrivial with CSS alone.  The closest I was able to get was with a flex reverse-wrap layout, demo below.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 4px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.one { height: 100px; }
.three { height: 125px; }
.five { height: 80px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one">1</div>
  <div class="box two">2</div>
  <div class="box three">3</div>
  <div class="box four">4</div>
  <div class="box five">5</div>
  <div class="box six">6</div>
</div>
```

However, you can see that items are arranged strictly in rows and are not packed efficiently.

Other alternatives include using `float: left` on each element or `columns: 4` on the container.  These are imperfect as well.

I recommend taking a look at [Masonry JS](https://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Bricks](https://github.com/callmecavs/bricks.js), frameworks for packing elements into columns.  They help abstract some of the complexity in achieving the layout I think you want.